# R Loop over Arima Model Error in `[<-.ts`(`*tmp*`, ri, only replacement of elements is allowed

Tags: r, loops, arima, group

Data Frame example:

```r
Country= c('Angola', 'Angola', 'Angola', 'Angola', 'Angola', 'Angola',  'Algeria', 'Algeria', 'Algeria', 'Algeria', 'Algeria', 'Algeria')
Year= c( 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002,2002, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002,2002)
Species= c( 'Goats', 'Sheep ', 'Goats', 'Sheep',  'Goats', 'Sheep',  'Goats', 'Sheep',  'Goats', 'Sheep',  'Goats', 'Sheep') 
Pop= c(20, 30, 22, 34, 18, 35, 24, 26, 40, 30 , 23, 43)

data <- data.frame(Country, Year, Species, Pop)
```

The loop function to predict animal population for the next 10 years per country and per specie :

```r
# Create a loop over each country
for (country in unique(data$Country)) {
  # Create a loop over each species
  for (species in unique(data$Species)) {
    # Filter the dataframe by country and species
    temp <- subset(data, Country == country & Species == species)
    # Fit the ARIMA model
    model <- auto.arima(temp$Pop)
    # Make the predictions
    pred <- predict(model, n.ahead = 10)
    # Store the predictions in a dataframe
    if (exists("newdata")) {
      newdata <- rbind(newdata, data.frame(
        Country = country, 
        Year = seq(max(temp$Year)+1, max(temp$Year)+10), 
        Species = species, 
        Predicted_Pop = pred)
      )
    } else {
      newdata <- data.frame(
        Country = country, 
        Year = seq(max(temp$Year)+1, max(temp$Year)+10),    
        Species = species, 
        Predicted_Pop = pred
      )
    }
  }
}
```

The code works on a singular country but does not work when looping , I get the following error:

> Error in `[<-.ts`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(7990484, 7990484, 7990484, 7990484,  :
> only replacement of elements is allowed

I understand the arima model is creating two lists (`pred` and `se`) time series object and `rbind` is the one not able to combine it as a dataframe? Any pointers will be appreciated.  I tried `replace()` function but still got the same error. Thanks!

I expect the loop to produce a list of animal population for each country and each species for future 10 years.

Comment: Thank you for reproducible example! One last item, please include all `library` lines as `auto.arima` is not a standard library method in R.

Comment: True,   it's the forecast library and its dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue likely is due to an empty `temp` when slicing data frame by unique values of *Country* and *Species*. Instead of nested `for` loops, consider generializing your process in a single function, then split your data frame into those groups with [**`by`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/by) or [**`split`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/split), and then process each split through your defined method. This will have you working with lists of data frames that you can then `rbind` *once* at the end.

```r
# User-defined method
predict_population <- function(temp) {
  if (NROW(temp) > 1) {
    # Fit the ARIMA model
    model <- auto.arima(temp$Pop)
    # Make the predictions
    pred <- predict(model, n.ahead = 10)
  
    # Store the predictions in a dataframe
    newdata <- data.frame(
      Country = temp$Country[1], 
      Year = seq(max(temp$Year)+1, max(temp$Year)+10), 
      Species = temp$Species[1], 
      Predicted_Pop = pred
    )
  }
}

# APPROACH 1:
# Filter the dataframe by country and species with `by`  
df_list <- by(data, data[c("Country", "Species")], predict_population)

# APPROACH 2:
# Filter the dataframe by country and species with `split`
# Run method with `lapply`
df_list <- split(data, data[c("Country", "Species")]) |> lapply(predict_population)

# RBIND ALL DFs TO MASTER DATA FRAME
new_data <- do.call(rbind, unname(df_list))
```

Comment: I used your thinking and approach and integrated it on my initial code now it works. I'll update it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Parfait suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75195157/5446749) I used his approach within my initial code:

```
    library(forecast) 
    results<- data.frame()
    
    # Create a loop over each country
    for (country in unique(data$Country)) {
       for (species in unique(data$Species)) {
    
    # Filter the dataframe by country and species
    temp <- subset(FAO.DB, Country == country & Species == species)
    
    # Check if the dataframe is empty
    if(nrow(temp) > 1){
    # Fit the ARIMA model
    model <- auto.arima(temp$Pop)
    
    # Make the predictions
    pred <- forecast(model, n.ahead = 10)

    # Store the predictions in a dataframe
    newdata <- data.frame( Country = country, 
                         Year = seq(max(temp$Year)+1, 
                                max(temp$Year)+10), 
                         Species = species, 
                         Predicted_Pop = pred)

    # Store the predictions in a dataframe
    
    results <- rbind(results, newdata)

           }
         }
     }
```

I have also changed function `predict()` by the function `forecast()`.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75194569/3) to the question [SOLVED R Loop over Arima Model Error in `[<-.ts`(`*tmp*`, ri, only replacement of elements is allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75194569/solved-r-loop-over-arima-model-error-in-tstmp-ri-only-replacement-o) by the OP [Pilar Rius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19001826/pilar-rius) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>